# How can I turn off TinyMCE deprecated messages

Tags: tinymce, message, deprecated

I have installed TinyMCE Version: 5.10.3 (2022-02-09)
this is the code:

```
       tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea.redactor-editor',
            plugins: 'preview paste searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable help charmap quickbars emoticons',
            menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
            toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist | forecolor backcolor removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | fullscreen  preview | image media template link codesample',
            image_advtab: true,
            height: 500,
            extended_valid_elements: "pre[*],script[*],style[*]",
            valid_children: "+body[style|script],pre[script|div|p|br|span|img|style|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5],*[*]",
            valid_elements : "*[*]",
            quickbars_insert_toolbar: '',
            quickbars_selection_toolbar: '',
            image_caption: true,
            quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote quickimage quicktable',
            noneditable_noneditable_class: 'mceNonEditable',
            toolbar_mode: 'sliding'
        });
```

and when I am landing to my page everytime it is showing this warning message:
The following deprecated features are currently enabled, these will be removed in TinyMCE 6.0. See https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/release-notes/6.0-upcoming-changes/ for more information. Plugins: - imagetools (moving to premium) - toc (moving to premium)

How can I turn off this message?

Answer (score 3):

add deprecation_warnings: false, to you're init

Comment: thanks it is working, but I can not vote until 15 to reputation